# Referring to other cells in R without using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am new to R and one thing I have been told again and again is that there really is no need for for loops.  I have had some success with apply but could not figure out how to use it in this instance.

Here is the data I am working with:

```
Bid  Ask     Exp Strike Price   V6
51 4.95 5.15 NOV1 13    335 5.050 3.08
52 3.40 3.50 NOV1 13    340 3.450   NA
53 2.28 2.42 NOV1 13    345 2.350   NA
54 1.51 1.57 NOV1 13    350 1.540   NA
55 0.99 1.07 NOV1 13    355 1.030   NA
56 0.66 0.71 NOV1 13    360 0.685   NA
57 0.46 0.51 NOV1 13    365 0.485   NA
58 0.33 0.37 NOV1 13    370 0.350   NA
59 0.25 0.28 NOV1 13    375 0.265   NA
60 0.18 0.24 NOV1 13    380 0.210   NA
61 0.11 0.20 NOV1 13    385 0.155   NA
62 0.05 0.17 NOV1 13    390 0.110   NA
63 0.05 0.16 NOV1 13    395 0.105   NA
64 0.07 0.13 NOV1 13    400 0.100   NA
```

In column 6 (called V6), I want the values to be twice the value in the price column in the cell that is 3 below the current row.  For example, Row 1 in Col 6 is 3.08 which is 2*1.54 which is in column 5, row 4.  I would like to do this for every cell in row 6 until it runs out in row 12.  NA is fine in column 6 after this row.

Here is how I accomplished this:

```
for (i in 1:11){ 
data[i,6] <- 2*data[i+3,5]}
```

Is there a faster/easier/ more appropriate way to do this?

Here is the final data as I want it.

```
    Bid  Ask     Exp Strike Price   V6
51 4.95 5.15 NOV1 13    335 5.050 3.08
52 3.40 3.50 NOV1 13    340 3.450 2.06
53 2.28 2.42 NOV1 13    345 2.350 1.37
54 1.51 1.57 NOV1 13    350 1.540 0.97
55 0.99 1.07 NOV1 13    355 1.030 0.70
56 0.66 0.71 NOV1 13    360 0.685 0.53
57 0.46 0.51 NOV1 13    365 0.485 0.42
58 0.33 0.37 NOV1 13    370 0.350 0.31
59 0.25 0.28 NOV1 13    375 0.265 0.22
60 0.18 0.24 NOV1 13    380 0.210 0.21
61 0.11 0.20 NOV1 13    385 0.155 0.20
62 0.05 0.17 NOV1 13    390 0.110   NA
63 0.05 0.16 NOV1 13    395 0.105   NA
64 0.07 0.13 NOV1 13    400 0.100   NA
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use   `mydata$V6 <- 2 * c(mydata$Price[-(1:3)], rep(NA, 3))`

Answer (score 0):

df1 is your data. I used `sapply` here which should be faster than `for loop`

```
df1$V6<-sapply(1:nrow(df1),function(x) 2*df1[x+3,5])
```

Comment: i doubt it will be faster than a for loop. worth benchmarking.

Comment: but based on your trick that out-of-range indexing returns `NA`, you can do `df1$V6 <- df1$Price[seq_len(nrow(df1)) + 3]`